# rails two buttons in a search form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a form_tag in my index page for performing searches on my model.

```
 <%= form_tag( :method => "get", :class => "form-inline") do %>
```

In the form I have two submit buttons that should direct to two different actions (two different views of displaying the search results.

```
  <div class="btn-group">
       <%= submit_tag("View1", :class => 'btn btn btn-success', :name => 'view1') %>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group">
       <%= submit_tag("View2", :class => 'btn btn btn-primary', :name => 'view2') %>
  </div>
```

When the view1 submit is clicked, I would like to it to point to the view1 action and load that page same as for view 2.

So in my controller I did the following:

```
  def index
    if params[:view1]
          render :action => 'view1'
      elsif params[:view2]
          render :action => 'view2'
      end
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html #{ render :layout => false }# index.html.erb        
      end
  end
```

but when I submit the form it redirects to the save action apparently. The url that is constructed is `http://0.0.0.0:3000/posts?class=form-inline&method=get` instead of something like `http://0.0.0.0:3000/view1?utf8=%E2%9C%93.....`

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got this to work

```
     <%= form_tag(root_path,  :method => "get", :class => "form-inline") do %>


   <%= submit_tag("view1", :class => 'btn btn btn-success', :name => 'view1') %>
   <%= submit_tag("view2", :class => 'btn btn btn-success', :name => 'view2') %>




if params[:view1]
     render :action => :view1


  elsif params[:view2]
     render :action => :view2
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def index
if params[:view1]
 @action = '/some/url'
else
  @action = '/some/url'
end

end
```

**Changing url in form**

```
<%= form_for('',url: view1) do |f| %>
--- fileds--
<%= submit_tag('conditional text') %>
<% end %>
```